# Placing R shiny widgets within mainpanel chart and altering valuebox to a different shape

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

What I am trying to achieve, is to produce a dashboard that looks similar to this:

[image]

I have tried to produce something similar using the iris dataset (ignoring the shape in the left hand corner).

However I am unable to move the drop down widgets (variable 1, variable 2, and variable 3) into the actual chart like in the image I attached.

In addition, is there a way to change the shape of the valueBox to being more similar to the image attached? Also with the font size being similar?

I attach a reproducible example using the Iris dataset:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(ggpubr)
library(corrr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)


dataset<-iris%>%
mutate(week=seq(from=as.Date("2017-03-12"), to=as.Date("2020-01-22"), by = "weeks"))


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style('.container-fluid {
                             background-color: Lavender;
              }'),
#tags$style(".small-box.bg-yellow { background-color: #FFFF00 !important; color: #000000 !important; }"),
# tags$li(div(img(src = 'iris.jpg', height = "75px"),tile="AAAAA",
# style = "margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; padding-top:-50px; padding-right:-100px;"),
# class = "dropdown"),
fluidRow(column(1,align='right',offset=7,
tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".small-box {height:50px}"))),
tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".small-box {width: 0px}"))),
div(valueBoxOutput("vbox"),style="color:white;"),style="background-color:#6724C6;",
style = "border-style: solid"),
column(4,align='right', dateRangeInput("week", "Week",width="400",
end="2020-01-22", start="2017-03-12"))),
fluidRow(
column(4,
selectInput("variable1", "Variable 1:",selected="Petal.Length",
choices=names(dataset[1:4]))),
column(4,
selectInput("variable2", "Variable 2:",selected="Sepal.Length",
choices=names(dataset[1:4]))),
column(4,
selectInput("variable3", "Variable 3:",selected="Species",
choices=names(dataset[5])))),
mainPanel(width=12,
plotOutput("distPlot"),
dataTableOutput("txt"),
verbatimTextOutput("write"),
),
fluidRow(column(12,textInput("caption","Caption","Data Summary"))))


server <- function(input, output) {

output$vbox <- renderValueBox({
valueBox(

value = tags$p( round(cor(q()[,input$variable1],
q()[,input$variable2]),2), style = "font-size: 100%;"),
subtitle = NULL
#   color="navy","R",

)  
})

q<- reactive({
dataset%>%
filter(week>= min(input$week)&
week<=max(input$week))
})


output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
print(ggplot(q(),aes_string(input$variable1, input$variable2))+geom_smooth())

})
output$txt<-renderDataTable({
datatable(
q()[,c(input$variable1,input$variable2)],
options = list(
scrollX = TRUE,
scrollY = "250px"
)        
)
})
output$write <- renderText({ input$caption })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```